# Puppeteer doesn't reuse cached fonts in Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, puppeteer, fontconfig

During PDF generation with Puppeteer new files appear in cache directory on Ubuntu 16.04 docker image (/var/cache/fontconfig) for each PDF (even the same one). Force `fc-cache -r` doesn't clean cached files in such situation

Is there a way to reuse cached fonts instead of generating new duplicates during PDF generation with Puppeteer and Chrome installed?